# Can I transform an object rotation while the animation is playing?

Tags: animation, constraints

I got a simple car. The front wheels are independent objects, linked to the body with a generic spring.
I want to change the frontwheels Z-rotation to change the driving direction.
The wheels are linked to an empty with an object constraint, to transform the rotation in relation to the empty.
This only works, if the animation is not playing.
Can I change the rotation while the animation is playing and the car drives (the back wheels got a motor constraint)?

Comment: of course you can. Best would be, if you provide your blend file so we can see what you tried and help you out.

Comment: could i recomend this video which i have used and find to be effective https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoSRMxMDYsk&t=1s